# Modificar formato de Excel exportado por GridView

Tags: asp.net, excel

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual cargo datos a mi GridView *(Datos Insertados)* desde mi Base de Datos.

Exporto mi GV en un Excel con este código:

```
private void ExportarGridExcel()
{
   int num = 0;
   Response.Clear();
   Response.Buffer = true;
   Response.ClearContent();
   Response.ClearHeaders();
   Response.Charset = "";
   lblcantidad.Text = num.ToString();
   string FileName = "Usuarios y Contraseñas" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
   StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
   GrillaDatosInsertados.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
   GrillaDatosInsertados.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
   GrillaDatosInsertados.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
   Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
   Response.End();
}

protected void Button2_Click3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ExportarGridExcel();
}
```

Esta es la interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar el boton, se exporta el gridview.

Lo que quiero hacer es darle formato texto a todas las celdas, ya que el campo *contraseña* obtiene números, y algunos tienen **0** al inicio, excel reconoce como si fuera un campo numero, y le borra ese **0**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Bueno encontré la solución en otro sitio de Google. Se las comparto por si alguien la llega a necesitar.

Inserté este codigo en el evento ***RowDataBound***

```
protected void GrillaDatosInsertados_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:@");
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:@");
        }
    }
```

Hace que todas las filas del Gridview tengan formato de texto.